# How to make taxonomy term name field work with 'Full HTML' text format?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

As taxonomy term name field supports only plain text, all I want is to use non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) for taxonomy name. Just to achive better html layout.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this? I've not heard of "&nbsp;" being a taxonomy of anything... perhaps you're trying to do something which could be achieved differently? Taxonomy for categorising things.

Comment: I added some details to make it clear). I created a views page to output all taxanomy term names in 4 column, so if the name is to long some words goes with new line. For example, THE ROOM IS NOT&nbsp;RESERVED.

Comment: Taxonomy functionality should not be used for layout, it will break things. For example each taxonomy term has a URL. Investigate Drupal theming, there's lots on it around. Plus it's a really bad idea to fix your functionality to one specific output. Set up your taxonomy terms then use other more suitable functionality for displaying your taxonomy terms, like you are with a view.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [check_plain](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7) function in your template file. Similar to what is shown in [this example](https://www.drupal.org/node/112352#comment-5890386) (which is for menu items though).